# Unable to override app name on mac os electron menu

Tags: electron

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one. I'm trying to override the name of a demo electron app to give it a custom name instead of just `Electron`. I created a module for doing this:

```
const {app, Menu} = require('electron')

const template = [
    {
        label: 'New Name',
        submenu:[
            {
                label: 'Test',
                click: (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
                    console.log('menu item clicked')
                }
            },
            {role: 'quit'}
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'test test',
        submenu:[
            {
                label: 'Test',
                click: (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
                    console.log('menu item clicked')
                }
            },
            {role: 'quit'}
        ]
    }
]

installApplicationMenu = function (){
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
    let result = Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
}


module.exports = {
    installApplicationMenu
}
```

And I'm invoking this module after creating my window:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

const {installApplicationMenu} = require('./MenuInstaller')


require('electron-reload')(__dirname,{
    electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron')
})

let win


function createWindow(){
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    })

    win.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        })
    )

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })

}

app.on('ready', function (){
    createWindow()
    installApplicationMenu()
})


app.on('activate', () => {
    if(win === null) createWindow()
})
```

When I do this the second menu set gets it's custom name of `test test` but the main menu name is still `Electron`:

[image: screenshot of menus not set]

I've been comparing the code to a different app I created where I was able to override the default name and I can't spot what's keeping the override from working in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you run your application in development environment using;

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron main.js
```

or

```
electron main.js
```

You are actually running a *prebuilt* `electron` executable that runs file specified by you. So in this case, the OS will display the name under which the application was built and packaged.

If you wish to change it, you need to package it. i.e. build your own distributable package. And to do this, there is an awesome package [`electron-builder`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder)

So install it;

```
npm install --save-dev electron-builder
```

And then build the package;

```
./node_modules/.bin/build -m
```

> Don't forget to set `productName` in `package.json`. It will be displyed in the menu on macOS, for example.
>
> `-m` is for macOS.

And you'll see packages in `/dist` directory. However, If you have a custom application format, it may fail to build, so refer to [README](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#README) or [wiki](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki) for details about application structure.

Answer (score 8):

I'm just getting back into Electron after not using it for nearly 2 years. From what I remember, you can't change the app name unless you package the app. Try something like this electron packager: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `productName` to your app name in the `package.json` of your app.

[image]

Comment: Please do not add images. Take at the best practices described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a question

Comment: @Renato to be fair I think images help a lot in questions and answers, I think where they don't help is if you're taking a picture of code you're trying to get help with, though even then it can be called for sometimes. Where the pics aren't helpful is if you give them without context or if the pic itself doesn't add context to the question or answer. I would also say the pic isn't necessarily adding value here, the rest of the text in their answer does enough, but yeah, u wouldn't make a blanket no-pics suggestion personally.

Comment: @Renato and the only reason I take the time to write that out is bc hello world seems like a new user so it's worth pointing out the nuance

Comment: the picture didn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this in dev you can simply edit the file
`node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Info.plist`
change the value below CFBundleName

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>Works Like a Charm</string>
```

[image]

Additionally you can install patch-package

```
npm i -D patch-package
```

Then

```
patch-package electron
```

this will generate patch which will take your changes and save in ./patches

add the prepare script to your package.json

```
{
   "scripts": {
     "prepare": "patch-package"
   }
}
```

thats how I dealt with my case

Answer (score -4):

You can set the name by adding `title` to the options you pass, when creating the BrowserWindow or use the instance method `win.setTitle("My App")`. The default value for that is `Electron` ([Source](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md))

```
function createWindow(){
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: 'My App'
    })

    // ...
}
```

Comment: this sets the name of a`BrowserWindow`, not the app menu name on `os x`